# How to make lock and home screen backgrounds separate

Tags: wallpaper

I have a Moto G 2014, and it's running 4.4.4. I cannot seem to find away to get my lock screen and home screen wallpapers different from each other. How can I go about doing this? I haven't rooted yet.

Comment: Just use the Google Photo app to set it. It will ask you whether you want to set a photo as wallpaper of the home screen, the lock screen or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default there is no setting to change lock screen wallpaper. One way is to have a lock screen app like Go Locker which will allow to set lock screen wallpaper different than the home screen wallpaper. Another is to install a custom ROM like Cyanogenmod 11 which gives much more features over stock OS.

Comment: Oh yes there is: just use the Google Photo app to set it. It will ask you whether you want to set a photo as wallpaper of the home screen, the lock screen or both.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a Moto G and I don't have the wallpaper background to be different from the lock screen. I figured out, by going through every setting, that there is no possible way for your wallpaper background and your lock screen to be different. But there is a solution. Either you can get a whole new phone (in which you can have a lock screen) or, you can suggest to the Motorola company to get a new setting to put up a lock screen.

Comment: The latter is unlikely to help the OP (even if Moto would comply, the day the update rolls out the device probably is no longer supported). And "buying a new phone" just for that is a poor (but expensive) solution.

Comment: Oh yes there is: just use the Google Photo app to set it. It will ask you whether you want to set a photo as wallpaper of the home screen, the lock screen or both.